# Why do includes() and indexOf() work differently with searching NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```js
//indexOf()
console.log([1, 2, NaN].indexOf(NaN)); //-1

//includes()
console.log([1, 2, NaN].includes(NaN)); //true
```

I don't get why `includes` can find NaN in array, while `indexOf` can't.

I've read that it's happening because `indexOf` uses strict-equality-operator internally (NaN === NaN). But as for me, there's no deffirence between strict-equality-operator and abstract equality operator when we're talking about `NaN`. `NaN` can't be equal to itself anyway.

```js
//strict equality operator
console.log(NaN === NaN); //false

//abstract equality operator
console.log(NaN == NaN); //still false
```

So why is there some difference between these 2 methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, `Array.prototype.indexOf` uses a different equality algorithm than `Array.prototype.includes`.

`Array.prototype.indexOf` ends up using [`Number::equal`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-equal). Which does:

> 1. If x is NaN, return false.
> 2. If y is NaN, return false.

While `Array.prototype.includes` ends up using [`Number::sameValueZero`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-sameValueZero)

Which does:

> 1. If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.

As to why does the spec allow a comparison of two different NaNs to be true, well that's up to the TC. I can only guess they made it this way as it's a convenient way to check if there's a `NaN` in the array.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by **TC** in your answer? What does this abbreviation mean?

Comment: Technical Committee. TC39 is responsible for ECMA-262 (EcmaScript)

Comment: @Ivan [TC39](//tc39.es).